# Vue2: view-router exception when trying to use <router-view>

Tags: javascript, html, webpack, vuejs2, vue-router

Taking my first stab at Vue2 and am stuck with routes.

Basically, when I added `<router-view></router-view>` to index.html I started receiving the exception:

```
[Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not 
defined.

found in

---> <Anonymous>
       <Root>
```

GitHub Code Link: https://github.com/kernelcurry/httpverbs-site/tree/c56ba0a45445f7d28c31cb6928471da3619a3327

I even looked up a video tutorial on this topic and they seem to have no problems, but I do.  (Video Link: https://laracasts.com/series/learn-vue-2-step-by-step/episodes/26)

To clarify, the error did not occur until I added `<router-view></router-view>` to `index.html` (Line Link: https://github.com/kernelcurry/httpverbs-site/blob/c56ba0a45445f7d28c31cb6928471da3619a3327/index.html#L10)

I wish I could give more insight into that is going on here, but I am at a loss.  Thanks to anyone willing to look at the code and point me in the correct direction :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `src/routes.js` as follows:

```js
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import Home from './views/home.vue'
import About from './views/about.vue'

let routes = [
    {
        path: '/',
        component: Home
    },
    {
        path: '/about',
        component: About
    }
];

export default new VueRouter({
    routes
});
```

Comment: Worked! But why?!  Why must `*.vue` files be imported at the top of the file instead of being required inline?

Comment: Because your vue files need to be transformed to plain javascript modules using webpack vue-loader, this is performed in your build process when it encounters imports.